# Azure authentication Audience validation failed

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I've built an ASP.net core Single tenant Web API that requires a token from Azure, I have also built a single tenant SPA via react that uses Azure to login Via MSAL-Brower. I want to use the token provided from  azure when I log in to authenticate my client SPA to call my API.
The token request comes back successfully but when I go to fetch I receive an error on my api stating that

> Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'System.String' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'System.String'.

I requested a token via MSAL Client method **acquireTokenSilent** with the scope of permissions established on Azure. Ive tried it all, Ive changed the ClientId and ResourceId in both the Client and the Web API.

```
const PostToDataBase = () => {
    const authenticationModule: AzureAuthenticationContext = new AzureAuthenticationContext();
    const account = authenticationModule.myMSALObj.getAllAccounts()[0]
    const endpoint = {
        endpoint:"https://localhost:44309/api/values",
        scopes:[], // redacted for SO
        resourceId : "" // redacted for SO
    }

    async function postValues(value:string){
        if(value.length < 1){
            console.log("Value can not be null!")
            return;
        }
        console.log(account)
        if(account ){
            console.log("acquiring token")
            authenticationModule.myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent({
                scopes: endpoint.scopes,
                account: account
            }).then(response => {
                console.log("token acquired posting to server")
                const headers = new Headers();
                const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
                headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
                headers.append("Content-Type", "'application/json'")
                const options = {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: headers,
                    bodyInit: JSON.stringify(value)
                };
                return fetch(endpoint.endpoint, options)
                .then(response => console.log(response))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
                if(err instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError){
                    if(account ){
                        authenticationModule.myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup({
                            scopes: endpoint.scopes
                        }).then(response => {
                            const headers = new Headers();
                            const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
                            headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

                            const options = {
                                method: "POST",
                                headers: headers,
                                body: value
                            };
                            return fetch(endpoint.endpoint, options)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .catch(error => console.log(error));
                        }).catch(err => console.error(err))
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
    }
    async function getValues(){
        
        console.log(account)
        if(account ){
            console.log("acquiring token")
            authenticationModule.myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent({
                scopes: endpoint.scopes,
                account: account
            }).then(response => {
                console.log("token acquired posting to server")
                const headers = new Headers();
                const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
                headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
                headers.append("Content-Type", "'application/json'")
                const options = {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: headers
                };
                return fetch(endpoint.endpoint, options)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(res => setValues(res))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
                if(err instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError){
                    if(account ){
                        authenticationModule.myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup({
                            scopes: endpoint.scopes
                        }).then(response => {
                            const headers = new Headers();
                            const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
                            headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

                            const options = {
                                method: "GET",
                                headers: headers,
                            };
                            return fetch(endpoint.endpoint, options)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(res => setValues(res))
                            .catch(error => console.log(error));
                        }).catch(err => console.error(err))
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
    }

    const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
    const [inputValue, setInput] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        // async function getinit(){
        //     const values = await fetch("https://localhost:44309/api/values")
        //     .then(res => res.json())
        //     .catch(e =>
        //         console.error(e))
        //     setValues(values)
        //     console.log(values)
        // } 

        getValues()
    }, [ getValues])
    return (
        <div>
            {values === undefined ? <p>no values to show</p> :
            values.map((n,i)=>( <p key={i}>{n}</p>))}
            <form>
                <input name="inputValues" value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=> setInput(e.target.value)} required></input>
            </form>
            <button onClick={() => postValues(inputValue)}>Post to Server</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostToDataBase
```

This is functional component that makes a call to the api, this pages is only accessible after the user logs in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

namespace McQuillingWebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //change to client url in production 
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Audience = Configuration["AAD:ResourceId"];
                    opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AAD:Instance"]}{Configuration["AAD:TenantId"]}";
                });

            services.AddControllers();
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my startup class where I configure middleware for Authentication

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource;

namespace McQuillingWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
 
        
        [HttpGet]
        [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            return Ok("Posted");
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

this is one of the generated controllers that I'm testing authentication with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the issue comes from the auth configuration in startup. Pls allow me show my code snippet to explain it well.

In my opinion, you could use `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);` instead. And you should exposed the api correctly.

The steps of exposing api, you can follow the documents. What I wanna repeat here is  when you generate an access token, it should have the scope like `api://clientid_of_the_app_exposed_api/tiny/User.Read` which can match the configuration in `appsettings.json`

My react code, it is referred to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/2-Authorization-I/1-call-graph/SPA/src):

```
import { AuthenticatedTemplate, UnauthenticatedTemplate, useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";  
const callApi = (accessToken) => {
            const headers = new Headers();
            const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    
            headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    
            const options = {
                method: "GET",
                headers: headers
            };
    
            fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/home", options)
                .then(response => {
                    var a = response.json();
                    console.log(a);
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        };
    
        const ProfileContent = () => {
            const { instance , accounts} = useMsal();
            const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);
            const loginRequest = {"scopes": ["api://clientid_of_the_app_exposed_api/tiny/User.Read"]};
        
            function RequestProfileData() {
                instance.acquireTokenSilent({
                    ...loginRequest,
                    account: accounts[0]
                }).then((response) => {
                    callApi(response.accessToken);
                });
            }
```

My ConfigureServices in startup file, these are referred to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

My appsettings :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "clientid_which_have_api_permission",
    "Domain": "tenantname.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "Audience": "clientid_of_the_app_exposed_api"
  }
}
```

My controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [RequiredScope("User.Read")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error message says that Authentication middle ware is not able to authenticate request successfully as Audience in the token is not part of Valid Audiences.
TO resolve this, you can mention what are the valid audiences in your configuration and your token shall have that audience. For checking audience in token, you can see the token fields in jwt.io
Also, if you want to skip Audience validation, you can do so while configuring authentication middleware by marking ValidateAudience as false.