# ADAL to MSAL react migration givening token unauthorization error

Tags: reactjs, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-msal, adal

I am migrating from ADAL to MSAL then getting the Unauthorized error when passing token into my api. (using React and .NET core ( .NET core 2.1 framework)

1. UIClient application is already registered then I have added SPA and add redirecturl.
2. Registered API application has added UIClient ClientId into
   Expose API -> Authrozied client application
3. MSAL is able to generate the token.
4. Sending token to API (using .Net core 2.1 framework)
5. Failed in authorizing the token, getting 401 unauthorized error from API code.

appsetting.json file contain setting

```
AzureAd{
   Authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
   ValidClientIds: ["Guid1","Guid2"],
   "AllowedIssuers: ["stsurl1","stsurl2"]
}
```

Startup.cs code

````
services.AddAuthentication(opt => {opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;}).AddAzureAdBearer(opt2 => configuration.Bind("AzureAd", opt2)); ```
````

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as it's being a while since the last time I work with ADAL and MSAL, but I think the error is because you're not passing the AUDIENCE parameter, which is a GUID format, rather than a URL.

Comment: can you please suggest me where should I add audience?

Comment: take a look in here https://stackoverflow.com/q/69199603/1384539

Comment: This might be an issue with the scopes you are passing on MSAL. Can you decode the accessToken acquire both with ADAL and MSAL, decode them on https://jwt.ms and look for differences? Are the "aud" and "scp" claims the same in both accesTokens?

Comment: Thanks @SérgioCorreia for response.  In both token aud is diffrent.  With adal getting correct aud but in MSAL getting 00000003-0000-00...... Where am I wrong?

Comment: what are the scopes that you are passing when you try to acquire the access token? That aud means that you are getting an access token for MS Graph, so there is definitely something wrong with the scopes you are using

Answer (score 0):

- Please check if the audience is matching the clientId of the
  application of the token is decoded in https://jwt.ms/. Audience
  mmatch the client iD and sometimes it maybe AppId URI of the app i.e;
  something like `api://<clientId>`.So please try checking for the same
  by changing  or also including clientId as both clientId and appId
  uri  or allowing both audiences.
- Also if thats not the issue try changing  `accessTokenAcceptedVersion`
  property of the  in the Web API app manifest in azure ad portal to 1
  or null if it is 2 or change to 2 if it is already 1 or null.
- Also please make sure that the scope of your web api
  (api:///) which is exposed after giving api permissions is granted `admin consent` either from portal
  itself or check with the admin .

Comment: Compared msal and adal aud, both are different.  Adal is giving correct one but MSAL is giving 00000003-000...... What is wrong I am passing from MSAL?    Is there any ado configuration issue?

Comment: aud value of 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 is for Microsoft Graph API,which  will get MS Graph token.To call your backend api which is not graph api, make sure you provide scope that particular backend api and grant admin consent .You can check [this](https://dev.to/czmiel24/configuring-scopes-in-azure-active-directory-part-1-3bio) blog for guidance. Also this [SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978170/azure-ad-authentication-with-net-core-web-api#:~:text=In%20the%20Azure%20Portal%20I%20navigated%20to%20Azure,in%20step%202.%20Then%20select%20%22Grant%20Admin%20Consent%22)