# Unable to verify the first certificate: WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application

I have a spa application that will create token and I need to validate the token in web api.The application is configured with the below approach in Azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

I am able to generate token in the Ui application but when I try to validate the token using postman it is throwing error
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Angular code: authconfig.js

```
    const msalConfig = {
    auth: {       
        clientId: "id",       
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/id",       
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },
    system: {   
        loggerOptions: {    
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {  
                if (containsPii) {      
                    return;     
                }       
                switch (level) {        
                    case msal.LogLevel.Error:       
                        console.error(message);     
                        return;     
                    case msal.LogLevel.Info:        
                        console.info(message);      
                        return;     
                    case msal.LogLevel.Verbose:     
                        console.debug(message);     
                        return;     
                    case msal.LogLevel.Warning:     
                        console.warn(message);      
                        return;     
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }
};


const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read"]
};

const tokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.Read"],
};
```

AuthPopUp.js

```
const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

let username = "";

function selectAccount() {


    const currentAccounts = myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();
    if (currentAccounts.length === 0) {
        return;
    } else if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
        // Add choose account code here
        console.warn("Multiple accounts detected.");
    } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
        username = currentAccounts[0].username;
        showWelcomeMessage(username);
    }
}

function handleResponse(response) {

  

    if (response !== null) {
        username = response.account.username;
        showWelcomeMessage(username);
    } else {
        selectAccount();
    }
}

function signIn() {

  
    myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

function signOut() {

  
    const logoutRequest = {
        account: myMSALObj.getAccountByUsername(username),
        postLogoutRedirectUri: msalConfig.auth.redirectUri,
        mainWindowRedirectUri: msalConfig.auth.redirectUri
    };

    myMSALObj.logoutPopup(logoutRequest);
}

function getTokenPopup(request) {

    /**
     * See here for more info on account retrieval: 
     * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/Accounts.md
     */
    request.account = myMSALObj.getAccountByUsername(username);
    
    return myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request)
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn("silent token acquisition fails. acquiring token using popup");
            if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
                return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request)
                    .then(tokenResponse => {
                        console.log(tokenResponse);
                        return tokenResponse;
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            } else {
                console.warn(error);   
            }
    });
}

function seeProfile() {
    getTokenPopup(loginRequest)
        .then(response => {
            callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, response.accessToken, updateUI);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

function readMail() {
    getTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
        .then(response => {
            callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMailEndpoint, response.accessToken, updateUI);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

selectAccount();
```

AuthRedirect.js

```
// Create the main myMSALObj instance
// configuration parameters are located at authConfig.js
const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

let username = "";

/**
 * A promise handler needs to be registered for handling the
 * response returned from redirect flow. For more information, visit:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md
 */
myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise()
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

function selectAccount () {

    /**
     * See here for more info on account retrieval: 
     * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/Accounts.md
     */

    const currentAccounts = myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();

    if (currentAccounts.length === 0) {
        return;
    } else if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
        // Add your account choosing logic here
        console.warn("Multiple accounts detected.");
    } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
        username = currentAccounts[0].username;
        showWelcomeMessage(username);
    }
}

function handleResponse(response) {
    if (response !== null) {
        username = response.account.username;
        showWelcomeMessage(username);
    } else {
        selectAccount();
    }
}

function signIn() {

    /**
     * You can pass a custom request object below. This will override the initial configuration. For more information, visit:
     * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/request-response-object.md#request
     */

    myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
}

function signOut() {

    /**
     * You can pass a custom request object below. This will override the initial configuration. For more information, visit:
     * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/request-response-object.md#request
     */

    const logoutRequest = {
        account: myMSALObj.getAccountByUsername(username),
        postLogoutRedirectUri: msalConfig.auth.redirectUri,
    };

    myMSALObj.logoutRedirect(logoutRequest);
}

function getTokenRedirect(request) {
    /**
     * See here for more info on account retrieval: 
     * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/Accounts.md
     */
    request.account = myMSALObj.getAccountByUsername(username);

    return myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request)
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn("silent token acquisition fails. acquiring token using redirect");
            if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
                return myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(request);
            } else {
                console.warn(error);   
            }
        });
}

function seeProfile() {
    getTokenRedirect(loginRequest)
        .then(response => {
            callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, response.accessToken, updateUI);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

function readMail() {
    getTokenRedirect(tokenRequest)
        .then(response => {
            callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMailEndpoint, response.accessToken, updateUI);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Graph.js

```
function callMSGraph(endpoint, token, callback) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${token}`;
    console.log`Bearer ${token}`
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    console.log('request made to Graph API at: ' + new Date().toString());

    fetch(endpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => callback(response, endpoint))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

GrpahConfig.js

```
const graphConfig = {
    graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    graphMailEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages"
};
```

In my web api projec I am using JWT authentication scheme

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "webapi", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "webapi v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domainnmae.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "id",
    "ClientId": "id"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        // The Web API will only accept tokens 1) for users, and 2) having the "access_as_user" scope for this API
        static readonly string[] scopeRequiredByApi = new string[] { "access_as_user" };

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
                          var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure If I am missing anything  in here or my approach is wrong. Please help me with your suggestions

Comment: do you have any update on it ?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I don't know what you were trying to implement...

Let's see why we got error in web api application. I noticed that you had code below in the controller.

`static readonly string[] scopeRequiredByApi = new string[] { "access_as_user" };`

Although the variable `scopeRequiredByApi` is not been seen used, according to the name, I think this is the api scope you are trying to validated. But in your SPA code, the scopes you set are `scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.Read"],` which is used for MS graph api, so they are not match, then the issue happened.

And ok, in your scenario, you set MS graph api scope in the Augular app, I'm not sure if you need to call ms graph api, if you need, I think you can already call ms graph api successfully. If you don't need to call ms graph api, you only want to call your own web api, then you should learn to [protect your web api by Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) first. This contained the tutorial about how to register app & expose api $ configure your code.

It can be summarized as, you need to make users sign in to finish the authentication first, then with the authentication, you need to use it to finish the authorization.

Since the api is your custom api, so you have to [expose API permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#expose-delegated-permissions-scopes) for it so that AAD can help manage and authorize for you. In your scenario, you need to expose delegated permissions.

Then you need to configure your code corresponding to what you did in Azure AD, including changing the scope in your Angular app to like `api://clientid_of_the_app_exposed_api/xxx`. Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph/TodoListClient) for web api. And you can also take a look at my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799358/14574199) for react + web api.