# How to integrate Microsoft authentication and authorization in full stack web app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, nestjs, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I am creating a full-stack web application using `Angular` and `Nest.js`.

I want to implement Microsoft authentication with `delegated` access for `Angular` so **User** can sign in using `Microsoft Login PopUp` on **SPA** and then they can access custom **protected APIS** from `NestJS` which can be deployed to any hosting server.

I researched and discovered that we have to create 2 `App Registration` one for the `Angular` itself and the other for the `NestJS`.

I also learned about two types of flow `implicit grant flow` and `authorization code flow`. whereas `implicit gran flow` is not secure and deprecated because of the `token leakage` problem.

I configured Frontend app registration for the frontend with redirect_uri, and for the backend as well **without** `redirect_uri`.

I also added `Expose an API` for `NestJS` and `API permissions` in the `My APIs` blade in the `frontend app client`.

The below image shows the `frontend client App`.

[image: frontend client App]

but I couldn't able to find out where to add URI for my localhost nest API and protect those APIs and how to integrate working both of these APPs. I am using `MSAL` for both.

Comment: I never used Angular and Nestjs, I only had [a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799358/14574199) with react + asp.net core web api before. it also containing related official documents.  and you can also take a look at the [official samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code).

Comment: the whole process can be summarized as, your SPA integrate MSAL so that you can sign in and generate access token for your web api. Here you need to set a scope for obtaining the access token, the scope is what you exposed API in Azure AD which should like `api://backend_api_aad_client_id/scope_name`, then the token you generating should have claim `scp: api://client_id/scope_name`. Then in your API project, you should also integrate AAD authentication, and you need to set several properties of the backend_api_aad including client id, client secret, audience and so on...