# How can I use an Azure AD login for my .NET API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I have a .NET 7 API that requires the user to have a Microsoft account. So to make it easier for the customer I want them to be able to login with their Microsoft account. The target audience is big organizations that often block their users from giving permissions to new apps. The simplest way I found to do this was to simply log the user in with only the "email" permission of the Microsoft Graph API.

I will briefly explain the current setup:

- I registered an AD app called "MyApi" in our Azure AD. It's open for all organizations and only has one permission: "email" (from Microsoft Graph API).
- I added a button to my front-end web app that sends the user to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[MyApi.ClientId]&redirect_uri=[MyApi.RedirectUri]&response_type=code&prompt=consent&scope=offline_access&response_mode=query](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%5BMyApi.ClientId%5D&redirect_uri=%5BMyApi.RedirectUri%5D&response_type=code&prompt=consent&scope=offline_access&response_mode=query)
- I then exchange the code for a token using the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token endpoint with scope = "offline_access".
- I then receive a token that has the audience: **00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000** (which is the Microsoft Graph API) and appId: **MyApi.ClientId**
- In the startup class I then do this:

```
IConfigurationSection azureAdSection = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
azureAdSection.GetSection("Instance").Value = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
azureAdSection.GetSection("Audience").Value = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000";
azureAdSection.GetSection("ClientId").Value = MyApi.ClientId;
azureAdSection.GetSection("ClientSecret").Value = MyApi.ClientSecret;
azureAdSection.GetSection("TenantId").Value = "organizations";
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(_configuration, "AzureAd");
```

I first tried it with a second Azure AD App that had exposed permission which I then used in the MyApi app. But this caused Azure AD Errors like this one:

```
AADSTS650052: The app is trying to access a service MySecondApp.ClientId that your organization [My TenantID]
lacks a service principal for.
Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions or consent
to the application in order to create the required service principal.
```

We then came to the conclusion that we probably don't even need this second app.

With the current setup everything seems to work fine, but is it the correct way?

By doing this I have a token that guarantees me that the user is a Microsoft user (which is reliable) and I can see what their email and id is. This data will allow me to find the matching user in our database and return the requested response. I have no need for custom scopes as all authorization and permissions are handled by the API itself.

In other posts and documentation there is a need for custom scopes or for using the token to call a downstream API (often the Graph API itself), all which isn't needed here.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an .Net 7 webapi, and you had `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(_configuration, "AzureAd");` in your startup file, so you are now [using Azure AD to protect your API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview). This protect means when a request reaching your API, it must contain a correct `Bearer access_token` in the request header. Here the `correct` means it should have correct audience, client id, scope/role, and it must be valid/not expired, etc.

So you have to have an Azure AD application(you already have it) and expose an API, then you can assign this API permission to this application(so that you don't have to create another AAD app). Then in your frontend application, you need to generate access token via this AAD app and setting the scope with the value you exposed just now, the value should looks like `api://client_id/permission_name`. Then the token should have  `"aud": "api://client_id",` and have `"scp": "permission_name",`. And this token should be able to bypass the validation of your web API.

In your API permission, you should have code and configurations like this:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "aad_client_id",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "TenantId": "organizations", // A guid (Tenant ID = Directory ID) or 'common' or 'organizations' or 'consumers'
    "Audience": "api://aad_client_id"
  },
```

To generate such kind of access token, you have to let user sign in first with MSAL. If your client app is written in react, maybe you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799358/14574199). Please note you need to set the scope to `api://client_id/permission_name` to generate a token containing this scope.

Comment: So I have an AD application for the users to log in which contains a permission to a second AD application where I expose an API. But why is that a good idea?
If I only have the first AD application with a basic "email" Microsoft Graph permission I know that:
1) The user is legit (microsoft user)
2) The user logged in via my AD application
What is the added benefit of the second AD application?

Comment: ` If I only have the first AD application with a basic "email" Microsoft Graph permission` --> then how can you generate a correct access token to visit your web API? Just like what I mentioned, you have your API with code `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` that requires you to have a correct access token when you add `[Authorize]` attribute in your controller. The token should containing a correct `scp` or `roles` claim. If you don't expose an API in your Azure AD and only have an `email` permission, then the access token only have `email` and maybe `user.read` or something else scope

Comment: which are used for MS graph API, but not your custom API, how can we bypass the authorization.... Could you pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement? anyway, what I did is based on ms official document, you can also have your custom code to realize your custom requirement.

Comment: If I understand it correctly if I use a second AD application "MySecondApp" this will mean that the token has the audience "MySecondApp" instead of "Microsoft Graph API", right? The problem then is that I get this error: AADSTS650052: The app is trying to access a service "MySecondApp" that your organization **** lacks a service principal for.
To avoid this I thought that maybe the "Microsoft Graph API" audience is enough to know that the user is authenticated?

Comment: `if I use a second AD application "MySecondApp" this will mean that the token has the audience "MySecondApp" instead of "Microsoft Graph API", right` --> yes. And about your question, tbh I don't know how to explain then. Let's assume you already got an access token, then I trust that the token you got should contain scp like `user.read email ...`, and when this token is valid to call an API? That API must need to validate scope which value is `user.read email`. Okay, so this API should be ms graph api, but not your own custom API.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know how to explain, and I also don't know how to follow your assumptions to realize your requirement.