# ASP.NET Core / React Authentification using Azure AD and Msal

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I am trying to secure my ASP.NET Core Web API and access it with my React client app. I followed the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763252/azure-authentication-audience-validation-failed/68799358#68799358?newreg=e0eb5fa32db2448e8bc3bc5bd02dc57d) posted by [Tiny Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14574199/tiny-wang), that helped me to understand the context.

Now I am still unable to call the API, I always get a 401 authentication error. My log from the API shows the following exception:

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foqJj.png)

I believe that there is something wrong in my Azure AD configuration, but I did it as described by Microsoft. Does anyone know where I could look further to fix this?

Thanks and regards,

Roland